# Symfony2 twig rendering error

Tags: php, symfony

Hey all I am trying to render a twig template in my controller but instead i get this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object
```

I followed few exampled on line and according to these I should be fine, unfortunately I guess I am doing something wrong.

My controller code:

```
<?php

namespace Tomazi\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Tomazi\SiteBundle\Factories\FactoryHomePage;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public $home;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryHomePage $home
    ){
        $this->home = $home;
    }

    public function indexPageAction()
    {
        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', [
            'name' => 'Tomazi'
        ]);
    }
}
```

So my twig file src is app/Resources/view/home.html.twig

in this file I have:

```
<h1>Hey {{ name }} </h1>
```

Why do i get this error message?

**Update 1**
OK so my controller was declared as a service, this did not allowed me to use twig container i belief....

I then went back and configured my controller to be just a Controller like so:

```
<?php
namespace Tomazi\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexPageAction()
    {
        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', array('name' => 'Tomazi'));
    }
}
```

I also had to of course change my routing so it does not expect a service but just a controller.

After these changes I was able render my `home.html.twig`, But this not satisfied me as I really wanted my Controller to be a service because I wanted to inject my Factories into it that will prepare all the data for the Controller to Respond and I like THIN controller approach...

To actually achieve my goal I had to add a service_container argument to my Controller service like so:

```
<!-- Controller -->
<service id="tomazi.sitebundle.controller.index"
         class="Tomazi\SiteBundle\Controller\IndexController">
    <argument type="service" id="tomazi.sitebundle.factory.index" />
    **<argument type="service" id="service_container" />**
</service>
```

Now my final version of a controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tomazi\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Tomazi\SiteBundle\Factories\FactoryHomePage;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public $home;

    public $container;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryHomePage $factoryHomePage,
        ContainerInterface $containerInterface
    ){
        $this->home = $factoryHomePage;
        $this->container = $containerInterface;
    }

    public function indexPageAction()
    {
        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', array('name' => 'Tomazi'));
    }
}
```

Not to sure if this is the best approach but it does the trick for me.

Comment: May be you can show full template code with base layout? It seems like somewhere called something like this: app.request.has('any_var'). But we need more details to define problem (may be more details from error trace)

Comment: Well am not even extending my base template, and my base template is Symfony generated

Answer (score 1):

OMG the reason why It was not working because my Controller was a service..... :@, I changed it so that my Controller is standard bang it works..... But I want my Controller to be a Service..... so how can I find a way around it...? is is possible to create Twig container as a service and inject it into my Controller Service?

Comment: Just call setContainer in your controller service definition: calls: [[setContainer,['@service_container']]].  By the way, better to update your question with this sort of thing than to provide an answer with yet another question.  Stackoverflow is a bit different then your average forum.

Comment: Ok sorry let me fix all this.

Comment: Done hopefully it looks better now :) thx for suggestion, what do you think of my final sollution @Cerad

Comment: I think calling setContainer using method injection instead of passing the container via the constructor is a cleaner solution.  But that is just an opinion.

Comment: How would I do this ...? could you show me a code snippet please

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection The controller base class already has a setContainer method so just need to add the call to your xml service definition.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code ?

```
public function indexPageAction()
{
    return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', array(
        'name' => 'Tomazi'
    ));
}
```

Comment: I did try this same result. I ave also cleared my cache just incase, But this error just want go away

Comment: array() and [] same things, this is not related the problem.